# Global Variable 'getInfo' is undefined

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm working on developing a GUI for a project and once I put all of this into a class, it is returning saying

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\users\ryan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Group_3_Project\Group_3_Project\Group_3_Project.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    b1 = Button(root, text = 'Submit', command = (lambda e = ents: getInfo(e)))
NameError: global name 'getInfo' is not defined
```

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import*


class GUI:
    fields = 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Field', 'Phone Number', 'Office number'

    def getInfo(entries):
        for entry in entries:
            field = entry[0]
            text = entry[1].get()
            print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))

    def makeForm(root, fields):
        entries = []
        for field in fields:
            row = Frame(root)
            lab = Label(row, width = 15, text = field, anchor = 'w')
            ent = Entry(row)
            row.pack(side = TOP, fill = X, padx = 5, pady = 5)
            lab.pack(side = LEFT)
            ent.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = YES, fill = X)
            entries.append((field, ent))
        return entries 

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tk()
        root.wm_title("HoursWizard")
        ents = makeForm(root, fields)
        root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e = ents: getInfo(e)))
        b1 = Button(root, text = 'Submit', command = (lambda e = ents: getInfo(e)))
        b2 = Button(root, text = 'Quit', command = root.quit)
        b1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        b2.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        root.mainloop()
```

I have no idea what is going on and why it isn't working correctly. I'm sure it is an easy fix and I'm just missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wrapping this all in `class GUI`?

Comment: I have more code that I am going to be putting in. This is just the GUI to get the users basic information.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) and look at the section on classes. Basically, your scoping and namespaces are not what you think they are. Every class method (unless it's been designated as static) is first passed the instance itself, usually denoted with `self`. You would then refer to instance attributes with `self.myattribute`. In `getInfo`, for example, what you call `entries` isn't entries at all, but rather the instance of the `GUI` class that has been created.

I highly recommend you look up some tutorials for how to make an OO Tkinter app. It generally goes like this:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.after(5000, self.other_method) # just a demo
        # create buttons, lay out geometry, etc.
    def other_method(self):
        self.do_print()
    def do_print(self):
        print('hello world')

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```